# HDAugmentedReality - How to scale the custom annotation views overlaid on the camera based on distances from nearby POI places in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, arkit

I am like extremely new to ARKit. I followed this tutorial down below

https://www.raywenderlich.com/146436/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based-2

which fetches nearby Point of Interests based on user's current location.

Those location are then displayed via a "custom annotationView" , sort of like a card shaped view which I created myself using ARKit when the camera is opened.

(NOTE: - I am not using unity. It's just a card shaped UIView which I created programmatically)

The cards are layed out just fine and in the respective directions of all those places. But, what I wanna do is I want to scale the views and make them appear exactly on the place which they are pointing to.

For eg, point A is nearer to me so it's visible on top of Point A, point B is further then point A so it will appear smaller but exactly on point B. The further I move towards point B the view should get bigger to a particular size.

Once, I move away or pass that place that view should stay as it is on that place and should scale itself to smaller size as I move away till it's no longer visible in my camera.

I would really appreciate it if someone has used this library and done it
https://github.com/DanijelHuis/HDAugmentedReality

At least, if not scaling, I would like the views to be placed at the same distance as the places are. if point A is 75 kms away it should be places 75 kms away on top of the place like a pin marker.

Please, help me out anyone :-(

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation
it shows items exactly above their real position. maybe it's helpful

Comment: I already have and i implemented it also in my project.But, some things dont work like the scaling and the camera suddenly freezes giving me an error, sometimes tho. That's why i took to stack overflow.But hey, anyways thanks anyways :-D

Comment: You're welcome :) for the scaling problem, what just came to my mind is to store all POI coordinates in a structure, then in the update(_:) method, which is called every frame, update all POI views sizes by comparing their coordinates with user's current location. Not sure about performance but might be a solution.

Comment: but, that's the thing bro..I dont know how to. I tried to understand the code but it just bounced on top of my head. I am totally new to ARKit, just two days ago i started working on this, I mean i did my best to try and mess around with the code, but zero results so far :(